# Reindexing Magento though SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, magento

is there a way to call the reindexing that you can fire off in magento's backend though an SQL statement?

i have a bunch of scripts which add products to magento and we need to reindex after it, we have a scheduled job that runs these scripts and i want to do the reindex after their done so that way it will always reindex after the scripts are done regardless how long they take (sometimes they can take a couple of minutes, sometimes half and hour, depending on what data needs to be changed, inserted or deleted)

the task scheduler is on a Microsoft SQL Server and magento is on a MySQL server (we use a link server apparently)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is not.

In Magento "re-indexing" means "run through a list of PHP classes and run their `reindexAll` methods".  Indexing strategy varies between indexer types. Most require reading some sort of data, doing programatic calculations, and then inserting values into flat tables.

For example, the catalog/URL rewrite re-indexer is the class

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Indexer/Url.php
(alias of catalog/indexer_url, PHP class of Mage_Catalog_Model_Indexer_Url)
```

Its `reindxAll` method contains

```
public function reindexAll()
{
    /** @var $resourceModel Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Url */
    $resourceModel = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/url');
    $resourceModel->beginTransaction();
    try {
        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/url')->refreshRewrites();
        $resourceModel->commit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $resourceModel->rollBack();
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

And the actual indexing is handled in the `refreshRewrites` method, which creates the needed Magento rewrites.

Comment: While you can't do it using SQL you can still do it through the commandline, ie. you could setup a cronjob or similar for it. To start the reindexing process you can call "php shell/indexer.php reindexall". And to see the status of the indexing you can call "php shell/indexer.php -- status".